# Lucence .NET sort by DateTime

Tags: lucene.net, lucene.net.linq

I use Lucene.Net.Linq to index data.Lucene.Net.Linq save datetime like 
"**2015-01-03T09:47:59**".

Now how I can sort index using raw Lucence .NET?
I test this but it`s not working :

```
 var sort = new Sort(new SortField("DateTime", SortField.LONG, false));
```

For your information filtering work with this code :

```
var dateFilter = new Lucene.Net.Search.TermRangeFilter("DateTime", startDate.ToString("s"),endDate.ToString("s"), true, true);
```

Comment: You're indexing your dates as strings, so why are you using `SortField.LONG` instead of `SortField.STRING`?

Comment: I test it with SortField.STRING also and not work

Comment: So, what happens? How do you index it?